# How to use InputMethodService in activity?

Tags: android

I have activity class

```
public class Login extends Activity
```

I create class inside Login class

```
public  class Keyclass extends InputMethodService
    {
        void addtext()
        {
            InputConnection ic =  getCurrentInputConnection();
             ic.commitText("1", 1);
        }
    }
```

And try to use it in onClick event:

```
Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    Keyclass kk= new Keyclass();
                    kk.onkey();
                }
            });
```

But get error:

> 02-26 21:28:18.903: E/AndroidRuntime(747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-26
>   21:28:18.903: E/AndroidRuntime(747): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

        // do what you want with the power button           
        Log.i(TAG,"PowerButton got clicked!");

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```